# Infinite continued fractions and convergents

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory, continued-fractions

I've got some question about infinite continued fractions and convergents:

**Given:**

$n = 205320043521075746592613$

$e = 70760135995620281241019$

$\frac{e}{n}=[0, 2, 1, 9, 6, 54, 5911, 1, 5, 1, 1, . . .]$

**Why $\frac{e}{n}=[0,2,1,9,6,54]$ is a good convergent?**

**Why don't we choose for $\frac{e}{n}=[0, 2, 1, 9, 6, 54, 5911]$ or $\frac{e}{n}=[0, 2, 1, 9, 6, 54, 5911,1]$?**

The book says you always have to stop before a big number. In this case 5911. Why?

Thnx for your help!

Answer (score 2):

A large coefficient means, that it needs a large new partial denominator to improve the previous approximation $\implies$ the previous approximation was (already) very good.

Comment: Can you please give an example of that situation?

Comment: @Lene - ??? Just compute the convergents of any synthetic continued fraction - $[1,2,9999,1]$ or $[1,2,3,9999999,1]$ step-by-step and see what happens with the improving of approximations...

Comment: Sorry, I still do not understand Why in my example, the best way is to stop by 54. In stead of 5911?

Answer (score 1):

The goal is to get a good rational approximation with a relatively small denominator.  If we didn't care about the size of the numerator and denominator, we'd just use the original fraction.  Also, I have read that one of the applications of continued fractions is in approximating desired gear ratios by combining gears with a small number of teeth.  A gear with 5911 teeth would be hard to machine, and fragile.

Comment: I like this real-life application of the theory. Plus one.

Comment: Thnx for the comment, but why in my example, the best way is to stop by 54. In stead of 5911?